# Switch PHP versions in the console, Ubuntu

Tags: apache-httpd, php

Trying to switch PHP versions at the shell in Ubuntu:

[image]

I'd like to switch from version 8.1 to 8.3. I complete the steps above and restart apache but my server remains using version 8.1?

[image]

Am I missing a step?

Moreover, at my console `php -v` my version is actually 8.3?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
sudo a2dismod php8.1 && sudo a2enmod php8.3 && sudo service apache2 restart
```